# What is the best way to have different configurations compile with different preprocessor flags on the same source code?

Tags: c, embedded, rtos

So say I have something like the following in a makefile.def:

```
MODLIST = src/main
CPPFLAGS+= -DCFG0=0 -DCFG1=1
cfg0.elf: CPPFLAGS += -DCFG=CFG0
cfg0.elf: $(addprefix $(ODIR)/, $(addsuffix .o, $(MODLIST)))
cfg1.elf: CPPFLAGS += -DCFG=CFG1
cfg1.elf: $(addprefix $(ODIR)/, $(addsuffix .o, $(MODLIST)))
```

and we have a dummy main.c with the following:

```
#if CFG == CFG0
printf("CFG0");
#elif CFG == CFG1
printf("CFG1");
#endif
```

The issue seems to be since they are being overwritten during compilation, (at least what I had thought but could be wrong) when both configurations get to that statement, they both print out the same "CFG0" in this case.

A couple ideas I had but ran into issues while trying to link...

1. Append something to the suffix like

> cfg0.elf: $(addprefix $(ODIR)/, $(addsuffix **_cfg0**.o, $(MODLIST)))

2. Append something to the output directory like

> cfg0.elf: $(addprefix $(ODIR)/**CFG0/**, $(addsuffix .o, $(MODLIST)))

I tried to modify the LDFLAGS but I didn't find a way to get it to compile correctly. Not sure if I was heading in the right direction or if there is a better way to go about something like this.

Comment: This is where we request a [mre] that demonstrates the behavior you are asking about.  What you have presented is not one, and it is not enough for is to work from.

Comment: What are the commands that are executed in the two examples?  Do you see the `-DCFG=CFG[01]` and related command line arguments?  Why are you defining `CFG0` and `CFG1` on the command line? It would be more usual to define them in a header or in the configured source, leaving the command line to specify `-DCFG=CFG0` or `-DCFG=CFG1`.

Comment: Thank you. I just fixed that now. It was just an error when I wrote it in the question. The reason for it to be in the makefile.def was because I wanted to compile out code that was unused since this would be used in 50+ source files. I had something similar to what you have mentioned before, but in that case the unreachable code isn't compiled out right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware when you using option `-DCFG=xxx` if the output `.o` are in same position because:

- `cfg0.elf` require all `.o` files in compile with `-DCFG0=0`
- `cfg1.elf` require all similar `.o` files but compiler detect that it was compiled already event with `-DCFG0=0` (because depend does not apply over compiler option. Then the `cfg1.elf` is linked with same file with `cfg0.elf`.

Your idea about `Append something to the suffix` or `Append something to the output directory` are all the right approach. Actually, I prefer `Append something to the output directory`. If you have problem with linking, I think you should raise question specifically for your linking issue.